# php divide with 'easy' numbers

Tags: php

I'm working on a program in PHP that lets you train for making calculations without a calculator. The problem I run into is that when generating random numbers for the sums you can get awkward numbers like 4 divided by 7. Is there an easy way to generate easy sums like 9 divided by 3?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use modulo to make sure the division is "easy".

Comment: Is the goal to generate calculations that don't have remainers?

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Paste some code. Otherwise use modulo

Comment: Generate two smaller random numbers and use those as your factors.  As long as one of them is not `1`, you'll be guaranteed *at least one answer* with integer divisors.  Post some PHP code, and we can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to generate two random numbers to multiply together. Get the answer to the multiplication problem. Then use the answer along with one of your original random numbers for your division problem. The answer will always be the second random number you generated.

Pseudo code:

```
$random1 = random(1, 100);
$random2 = random(1, 100);
$answer = $random1 * $random2;
print("What is $answer / $random1?"); // answer is always $random2
```

You don't explain what range of random numbers you are using, but be careful not to pick 0 for $random1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

suppose there are two numbers you get at random $a and $b. If u want to divide $a by $b check if $a>$b and then check if remainder is zero. $a%$b==0; if yes you can echo the values.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this code, but it should check if the division is easy or not, using the [modulo character %](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php), and call the function again if it is not easy. If the division is easy, it returns the numbers as an array.

```
function easyDivide() {

    // Code for generating random numbers

    if($num1 % $num2 != 0) {
        return easyDivide();
    } else {
        return array($num1, $num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your first pair doesn't produce an easy division, your function won't return anything.

Comment: @gre_gor, yeah, but it would call the function again. Making another pair of numbers.

Comment: It's not returning anything from your second call.

Comment: @gre_gor, oh. Since it is just calling the function again, without any way to actually return the values?

Comment: While not an infinite loop in the traditional sense, this has the possibility of never succeeding.

Comment: @Kodemikkel Yes it should be `return easyDivide();`

Comment: @gre_gor, thank you for pointing out, edited my answer.

Comment: @Rick, yes, technically it could go on forever. Should probably have a check to avoid that.